# How to stop a Powershell WPF Form from closing

Tags: wpf, forms, powershell

I have been trying to implement a way to stop the user from manually clicking the red 'x' on my WPF form in Powershell. Research online indicates that the best way to do is to use a the form closing event, stop the event and hide the form instead. It seems there are many methods of doing so in C# but i cant seem to find any for Powershell. For example, something like this can be used in C#.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

is there anything equivalent I could use in Powershell?

The event for form closing in Powershell is `add_Closing`, but I cant figure out how to stop the closing of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is how simple it was:

```
 $form.add_closing
    ({
        $_.cancel = $true 
    })
```

Just a quick note, this will work if you are using a WPF form. If you are using a WinForm, you will have to use the `[System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler]` to make it work.